# Generics and casting

Tags: c#, generics

```
class B : A {}
class Sub<T> where T:A
{
//...
}
```

I want to store Sub instances in a collection.

```
var c = new List<Sub<A>>();
c.Add(new Sub<B>()); //doesn't work
```

However, to get it to actually work, I have to declare an interface and store instances of that interface.

```
interface IBase
{
    void DoStuff(A a);
}

var c = new List<IBase>();
c.Add(new Sub<B>()); //works
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Using the interface approach it's perfect!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. Instantiations of a generic type with different type arguments are completely unrelated. The only way you can get them in the same list is by having the list use a common non-generic base class or interface, as you did here.

You can achieve an approximation of what you want by using a covariant generic interface:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

interface ISub<out T> where T : A
{
    // Members go here
}

class Sub<T> : ISub<T> where T : A
{
    // Members go here.
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
List<ISub<A>> list = new List<ISub<A>>();
list.Add(new Sub<B>());
```

You need an interface because only interfaces can have covariant or contravariant type parameters.

Comment: I was hoping the generics constraint where T:A would make it work :(

Comment: @jameszhao00: the reason you need covariance for this is because without it, you could have a function in your generic class like `void Foo(T value)`. If a `Sub<B>` is then cast to a `Sub<A>`, it would allow you to call that function passing an instance of A, while it only accepts instances of B. By specifying that the type parameter is covariant, you cannot have a function that takes an argument of the generic type in the interface (the compiler won't compile it).

Answer (score 4):

Depends on how you use it, but perhaps you could use a covariant interface for `Sub`:

```
interface ISub<out T> where T:A
{
}
```

Then `ISub<B>` can be implicitly converted(via a reference conversion) to `ISub<A>`